# Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2

> Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'referenceBlock':
>   This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer,
>   container, update, move ). Line: 1

I got this error while trying to remove page title through **Design** -> **Layout Update XML**

This the code I used to remove block:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
```

**referenceContainer** works fine but problem only with **referenceBlock**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I got the solution, used **referenceBlock** inside the **referenceContainer** works fine, may be anyone help.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title" remove="true"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and what I would have done to solve it was the answer by the previous post accepted answer:)

So what I could add this is that this error highly likely has to do with a  magento migration for ones who are interested...

> Please correct the XML data and try again. Element 'reference': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( referenceContainer, container, update, move, head, body ). Line: 1

CONTENT->PAGES-> PAGES (ELements) once you opend your page its a wrong coding in the field under the DESIGN -> LAYOUT UPDATE XML .

So when facing this on the new Magento 2.2.6 version ...

I removed it and saved the page and error disapeared and page was saved sinds the setting was coding for style upfate of old template for magento 1.9x that wasn't needed anymore anyway